# Is there a way to check more than one matches with a minimum value from a relation table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I have 2 relational tables "users" and "user_categories".(In user categories table 'user_id' and "category_id" is being saved)

Now I need to search users who has a common category matching with a percentage value.

More clearly, I am receiving 2 values in my request 1. array of Category Ids to be matched. 2. Percentage to be matched .

So If category_ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

and percentage_value = '100%';

Then the out put should have all the users who match all the 10 category ids.

If percentage_value = '30%';

Then the out put should have all the users who match any 3 category ids.

Now If I use 'whereIn()' it returns the users who match minimum 1 value, which is not my required thing.

This is much complicated to make such query. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should name your pivot table `category_user` to follow [Eloquent naming conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Second, take the intersection of the array of category ids received and the category ids associated with the user. Then calculate the percentage of the intersction / total and compare that against the threshold value:

```
// filter only users with at least "percentage_value" or greater matching category ids.
$users = User::all()->filter(function (User $user) {
    $userCategoryIds = $user->categories->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $ids = array_intersect(request()-get('category_ids'), $userCategoryIds);
    return (count($ids) / count(request()->get('category_ids'))) >= request()->get('percentage_value');
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I have proper naming convention etc.Posted an example here to explain my problem.Let me try this.

Comment: Thanks some mistakes there in your comment in request function arrow is not completed and instead of array_diff it should be array_intersect. But still I am marking your answer as correct because you give the answer very quickly and shown me the exact way where should I go. Thanks a lot and a great respect for you.

Comment: Good catch on the intersect vs diff. I've updated the answer with your suggestions. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Eloquent but below is the sql syntax for the query with a ":givenPercentage" parameter to be bound with your percentage.

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS user_cats 
    FROM user_categories GROUP BY user_id) user_cat_count
WHERE
    user_cats / (SELECT count(category_id) FROM categories) > :givenPercentage
```

You are effectively creating a subquery to count the number of categories each user is in. Then you are comparing the counts with the total categories in the where clause and checking if it is above a certain percentage.